# REST service, always give 404 Context Root Not Found error for the first time request, then work well

Tags: websphere, ibm-cloud

In my REST service, once I start or restart my websphere application server and do a request at the first time, the response will return 404 Context Root Not Found error, after this, do requests on this REST service can work well.

The problem is that the 404 error is always return at my first request after my server start.

Could you give some suggestions?

Comment: Can you share your web.xml where you define your service endpoints? Are you using annotations?

Comment: Does it happen no matter how long you wait before you issue the first request? Are you pushing a WAR or a server package/dir?

Comment: Yes, it happen no matter how long I wait before my issue the first request, and I pushing package to the server

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
 version="3.0">

  <display-name>ServiceManagerAPI</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>

Comment: Could you try to follow the sample web.xml in http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/twbs_jaxrs_configwebxml.html?cp=SSEQTP_8.5.5%2F1-3-0-28-2-0-1 and see how that goes?

Comment: Did you try looking at the logs? You can connect with `cf logs <appName>` and see it real time while you do your first request. Do you see any race condition when you trigger the request? Otherwise, what do you see in the logs at that time?

Comment: @XiangyuYang are you still having this issue?